# Websphere portal serialization error

Tags: java, performance, serialization, websphere-8, websphere-portal

My SystemOut log is filled with:

```
                                                        E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
[7/24/14 17:20:12:253 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMHashMap handlePropertyHits SESN0202E: Failed to replicate attribute javax.portlet.p.Z7_JH56H4K0KO8C00ACRD944B2042?view
[7/24/14 17:20:12:254 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
[7/24/14 17:20:12:254 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMHashMap handlePropertyHits SESN0202E: Failed to replicate attribute javax.portlet.p.Z7_JH56H4K0K8MP90AS8PIGS60432?view
[7/24/14 17:20:12:254 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
[7/24/14 17:20:12:254 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMHashMap handlePropertyHits SESN0202E: Failed to replicate attribute javax.portlet.p.Z7_JH56H4K0KO8C00ACRD944B20K1?view
[7/24/14 17:20:12:255 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
[7/24/14 17:20:12:255 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMHashMap handlePropertyHits SESN0202E: Failed to replicate attribute javax.portlet.p.Z7_JH56H4K0K8MP90AS8PIGS604J4?view
[7/24/14 17:20:12:255 GMT+05:30] 0000000a WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
```

I am not able to get the exact cause, I Googled and found that it is caused by a serialization issue, but I don't understand where I should correct this. Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: This is far too little information for people to find out what your problem is. But I would start looking what attribute "javax.portlet.p.Z7_JH56H4K0K8MP90AS8PIGS604J4?view" contains. Did you create your own portlet? Are you using a 3rd party portlet? If so what portlet, and where is it storing information in an attribute? etc. etc.

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual exception that was thrown and the stack trace? Perhaps by increasing the logging level?

Comment: If there isn't a way to get the actual exception, I would consider this a WebSphere Application Server serviceability defect, and I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM. You shouldn't have to guess at what's wrong to diagnose the problem.